# Jquery - Send variables to a controller Action via GET in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

All,

I want to send a variable "itemId" via GET to a controller action through AJAX. In the Controller Action, I should be able to retrieve the value using `$_GET["itemId"];`

Can I send the querystring with "data" tag instead of appending it to the "url"?

I have the following code:

```
  $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "/controller/controlleraction",
          data:  itemId,
          cache: false,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(html_input)
            {
              alert(html_input);
            }
        });
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/controller/controlleraction",
      data: ({itemId: itemId}),<------change it to this
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(html_input)
        {
          alert(html_input);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`data: {itemId: itemId},`

Answer (score 0):

Make itemId a JavaScript object before making the AJAX request. For example:

```
var itemId = {'itemId': 1000};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data: {itemId: "you info"},

or

data: "itemId=you info",
```